# Error in python selenium-webdiver script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

it's login is fine, but i am not able to track the issue, here the code below

```
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/?wo=1")
```

I am getting this error when i ran project.py

```
Superuser$ python project.py

user diabruxaneas1989 with proxy 192.126.184.130:8800 running 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "project.py", line 158, in <module>
Main()
File "project.py", line 94, in Main
username = browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"id_username"}
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/rc/vx_d14f14p97l02f35j6_dvw0000gn/T/tmp6I93xt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///var/folders/rc/vx_d14f14p97l02f35j6_dvw0000gn/T/tmp6I93xt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/rc/vx_d14f14p97l02f35j6_dvw0000gn/T/tmp6I93xt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/rc/vx_d14f14p97l02f35j6_dvw0000gn/T/tmp6I93xt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/rc/vx_d14f14p97l02f35j6_dvw0000gn/T/tmp6I93xt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

I tried other solutions as well but still same error .

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Show us `HTML` for Username input field

Comment: you can get it from 
https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login

Answer (score 1):

You need to start using the `wait` variable which is an instance of `WebDriverWait` class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id_username')))
```

This would wait until the `username` input becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

you said in comments that the page is https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login, but in your code you use browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/?wo=1"), obviously it's not the same page and your problem might be that in https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/?wo=1 there is no element with id `id_username` while on page https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login there is element with id `id_username`.